# Does Graphviz support association classes?

Tags: uml

I generated some UML diagrams with Graphviz. Now I would like to add association classes. Is this possible with Graphviz?

Comment: What are "relation classes"?

Comment: For example a custom implementation of IEnumerable is a relation class. This is for 1:N relation. There might be relation classes for 1:1 relations also. I'm not sure about the uml standard, i was teached like this: if you have relation A -> B a relation class is drawn as an extra Node which is connected to the edge between A->B. Of course this is not standard graph, that edge can have a node connected. But the ood teacher told me there would be something in uml for that too.

Comment: Uhm, what? Now what is IEnumerable?? You should not answer in riddles.

Comment: You probably mean **association class**?

Comment: actually its some time ago since i heard this. maybe they kicked it out of the uml spec because it's not a standard graph and you can easily image it with a class in between with standard graph notification. This question seems like another issue for a dislike :p

Comment: Yes, assosciation class should be the word. sorry. IEnumerable comes from .NET, sorry i wass missing i'm not in .NET context now. IEnuemrable is a interface for objects that implement 1:N relation (Association with cardinality N)

Comment: yeee asoc class. Heres the definition: http://etutorials.org/Programming/UML/Chapter+6.+Class+Diagrams+Advanced+Concepts/Association+Class/

Comment: I can't help with graphwiz, but maybe others. You should remove the "is there a similar" part of your question because it's regarded off topic on SO.

Comment: Is graphwis different from graphviz (or graphwis is only a Viewer of graphviz files)?

Answer (score 2):

In Graphviz, there is no things to support UML. We should create them.

Try this (the most similar way to show Association-Class):

```
digraph hierarchy {
  size="5,5"
  node[shape=record,style=filled,fillcolor=ivory]
  edge[dir=back, arrowtail=empty]

  2[label = "{A|+ x\n+ y|...}"]
  3[label = "{B|...| + method1()\l...}"]
  4[label = "{C|...| + method2()\l...}"]

  _23[shape=point label=""]

2-> _23 [dir=both arrowtail=none arrowhead=none]
_23 -> 3 [dir=both arrowtail=none arrowhead=none]
4 -> _23 [style=dotted arrowhead=none arrowtail=none]

}
```

see [**Online Demo**](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/bP7DJiCm48JlUOfLJg26IAJjqQZ0OwGLShDBRU5ueutv2KtV7Ri157hZP8tdc_NOtlH1ItXjNORs8BepO2o9biOCSCm0Ulj9AbyNwpmApqXrRtH7IgXXmQ8FWoFrR9qZBDBIi6DHzerbsCK4uO5gjABskdafG8lmUz3MAMgx48c8LBNJUtAW83_UZmlusFe536DPbgSyZLZE_8UqFS82MWg6yVRgUkj-mTKCVFmBLZCmaa_LyliQ7LiVu9nJUJAhcxjamrIQWvbrzknfaeOqdkKkIt3C_2EnWfypfjT33e7m0hiO4fjbfsn37kDNVG40)

If you want an extension that support UML:

You can use **PlantUML** (see [reference 2](http://plantuml.com/)), the add-on for the Graphviz tool that allows you to write a textual definition of UML diagrams.

In PlantUML, you can work with **all relationships between classes** (see [reference 3](http://plantuml.com/class-diagram)).